# What should be in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

What should be in the FAQ?

Answers should refer either to a global issue (e.g. language issue, formatting issue of the FAQ itself) or to just a unit of information, so that voting and editing is easy.

Answer (score 5):

The FAQ should contain a paragraph about other resources:

Have you tried the following online resources before posing the question?

- Google
- (List of online dictionaries) or Link to list of online dictionaries
- (List of etymological links) or link to the list
- Google Labs Ngram viewer http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22Gutmensch%22&corpus=8&smoothing=3
- Wiktionary http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite
- Wikipedia http://de.wikipedia.org
- Wörterbuchnetz with 24 dictionaries, http://woerterbuchnetz.de/

Answer (score 2):

I would like to have completely separate FAQ pages in German and English and a language choice button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important points is, the FAQ has to clarify what is on-topic and what is off-topic. Until that is done, closing questions as off-topic is rather arbitrary.

Please compare the FAQ of some established sites like SO, SF or EL&U with that of sites in Beta like our.

> German Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for students having
>   questions about German, expert speakers of German wanting to discuss
>   the finer points of the language and translation questions from any
>   language to German.

is a good start, but I think it needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

A paragraph on the used language:

We welcome questions in English or German. Do not be surprised if your question is edited to improve the language.

Answer (score 0):

It should point out clear and direct the mechanism of this page:

- one question
- many answers to this question
- comments only for clarification

This is a thing I usually comment on new user that writes a follow-up question as answer. And while writing this answer, I realized I can point to the reworked tour-page.

Lets check the pages:

- https://german.stackexchange.com/tour Tour page

  - **it is written only there**
  - Headline: Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
  - small body: This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
  - big pic
- https://german.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange Our Model

  - code of conduct: no hint
  - expected behaviour: no hint
  - (scrolling for listed questions hinting)
  - How to not be a spammer : not here
  - (nothing else sounds like)
- https://german.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

  - it is written here
  - concerning about a deleted question - not where *I* would look up  before a deletion

So I'd like to recommend to integrate the tour information into "our model" - because I assume the help section is the compendium of any helping topic.